# Sharing Files Across Projects in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, xcode4.2

I have two projects in an Xcode workspace and I want to be able to use the code from one project in the other without having to move the file over (would kill the point of being able to have multiple projects in a workspace).

When I try to import a header file from another project, Xcode claims that it cannot be found.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the target project (the project in which you are trying to #import files), you may need to define an additional search path so Xcode can find the files. Although I thought that one of the advantages of workspaces was that Xcode just "knew" about all the files of all the projects in the workspace, thereby making this a moot issue...

Comment: That was my understanding as well. Oh well, adding the search path worked. Thanks!